# Check if every string in a set contains equal number of 'a' and 'b' okay I tried again will some one work something out now?

Tags: c++

Will some one explain or make a program in c++ of this for me? Got assignment but don't know how to do it.

Question:  You are given a set of strings which contain only `a`s and `b`s, your program should be able to check whether each string has the same number of `a`s and `b`s in it or not.

e.g. The program will respond `true` if it get `{ab, aabb, aaabbbb, bbbaaa}` and say `false` when it gets `{aab, bbba, aaabbbb}`

Solve it using stack

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int count1 = 0;
int count2 = 0;

bool isInLanguageL (string w);

int main()

{
    string input;

    cout << "Input any string; ";
    getline(cin,input);

    if (input.length() % 2 != 0)
        cout <<"Pattern entered does not match the language ";
    else
        isInLanguageL(input);

    return 0;
}

bool isInLanguageL (string w)
{
    stack<string> word1, word2;
    string a, b;

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < w.length()/2; i++)
    {
           a = w.at(i);
           word1.push(a);

    }

    reverse(w.begin(), w.end());

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < w.length()/2; i++)
    {
           b = w.at(i);
           word2.push(b);

    }


while(!word1.empty() && !word2.empty())
{


    word1.pop();
    count1 = count1++;
    word2.pop();
    count2 = count2++;

}

if(count1 == count2)
    return true;
else
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225500/discussion-on-question-by-mazhar-jr-check-if-every-string-in-a-set-contains-equ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is using stack, please refer to the comments written in the code. If you have any doubt you can comment them.

**Code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void checkString(string s) {

    if (s.size() % 2 != 0) {
        cout << "Doesn't satisfy the conditon\n";
        return;
    }

    stack<char> st;
    int n = s.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

        /*
            case - 1 : If the stack is empty you can directly push the current character into the stack
            case - 2 : If there are elements present in the stack, then if the current character is equal to the top character on the stack then we can push the current character
                       beacuse we didn't find any new character to match them.
        */
        if (st.empty() || (st.top() == s[i])) {
            st.push(s[i]);
        }

        /*
            case-3 : If the stack is not emtpy and current character is different from the top character on the stack then we found a match like a-b (OR) b-a, so then we will
                     remove the top element from the stack and move to next character of the string
        */
        else if (st.top() != s[i]) {
            st.pop();
        }
    }

    /*
        case - 1 : After iterating through all the characters in the string, if we find the stack is emtpy then we can say all characters are not matched
        case - 2 : If stack is emtpy, then that means all the characters are matched.
    */
    (st.empty()) ? (cout << "Yes, satisfies the conditon\n") : (cout << "Doesn't satisfy the conditon\n");
}

int main() {

    string s = "";

    cin >> s;
    checkString(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's perfect

Comment: @MazharJr.   But make sure you understand it; particularly the funky use of the ternary conditional operator at the end.

Comment: Yes trying to understand

Comment: @MazharJr.: Yes it's high-quality code, although I'd drop the `using namespace std;` in order to set a good example. `int` for the size is a bit naughty too: if Sai was in my shop I'd punish him with a 6 month sentence on the Java team for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution has a number of mistakes that you should probably solve by using a debugger. Here's a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173).

---

This solution doesn't use a stack as you asked for, but you can write this function that uses algorithms to solve your problem:

```
namespace rs = std::ranges;

bool all_equal_as_and_bs(auto const & strings) 
{
  return rs::all_of(strings, [](auto const & string) 
         {
             return rs::count(string, 'a') == rs::count(string, 'b');
         });
}
```

And use it like this:

```
all_equal_as_and_bs(std::vector<std::string>{"ab", "aabb", "aaabbb", "bbbaaa"}); // true
all_equal_as_and_bs(std::vector<std::string>{"aab", "bba", "aaabbbb", "bbbaaa"}); // false
```

Comment: It's a useful answer, have an upvote - I'll clean up my first comment.

Comment: How about including the statement `using pointless = std::stack<void>;` somewhere in the answer? (Intentionally non-instantiable but I believe the compiler must compile it - if anything that will wind up the professor!)

Comment: @Bathsheba I thought of it, but I don't like being too cheeky in answers :) Your comment should suffice ;) Besides, while a stack is pointless here, I assume the OP is at that point in their class, and this question is just to give them practice with stacks. Also, I intentionally provided a C++20 solution, so the OP can't submit it directly. I'm unaware of any institution that actually has a testing framework that compiles C++20 yet.

Comment: Silly exercise though. If you want practise with stacks then build an expression parser.

Comment: @Bathsheba Absolutely. But I do some teaching myself, and I'm confident this is just a misguided exercise to teach a concept. Happens a lot unfortunately. There are simpler, and useful cases for stacks than building an expression parser though :)

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes just studying in some bad university had to gone through these kind of stupid things

Comment: @cigien: My first use of a stack was building something to colour in an irregular shape with "islands" in it - in Z80 machine code. Happy days. Yup, simpler than an expression parser.

Comment: @Bathsheba Oh my, Z80 machine code? You've been in the game too long ;)